# Is 91 http requests too much for a web page load?

Tags: javascript, html, http, web, architecture

We are running a asp.net web application, recently we received a lot of crash reports from user. It sometimes crashes Chrome browser, sometimes it loads infinitely.

This is how our system is designed: our page is light weight HTML5 page, there is no code behind in our page, ie, no server side binding. Once page is loaded in browser, it fires up ajax requests to load up everything it needs, from look up values to business model, then it uses JavaScript to bind it to drop down lists, and other DOM elements.

This is the screen shot from Chrome browser developer tool

[image]

Is 91 http requests too much for a browser? How do I eliminate this is not the cause of browser and application crash ? Thank you fellow programmers !

Comment: Consider moving this to [Webmasters SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: There is a limit to HTTP requests per domain, then it queues all other requests. That is why companies use multiple sub-domains to load things like images. You could benefit by doing the same. It should be easy to point a sub-domain to the same code and fire it, so the change is quite simple and no programming (other than the changing some of the calls to call from a "different" place) required. It should speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

91 simultaneous requests is a lot for a single client using http 1.1, particularly for mobile, but if those requests are lightweight and offset even by a few hundred ms from one another, it may not be the cause of crashes or major lag. Anyway, you can do things like concatenate media files (js, css, and sprites) to reduce lots of small requests into a few larger ones. Use YSlow, Google Webmaster Tools and anything else at your disposal to help determine what to do and how to do it.

That said, [http 2.0](http://http2.github.io/) is designed to handle lots of small requests better, so be prepared as servers and clients gain the ability to accept that protocol.

Also don't forget to evaluate that the hardware is enough to meet the projected demand.